# Ресурсы и массивы

Tags: android-sdk, android

У меня есть двухуровневый список, хочу добавлять в него элементы редактируя только файлы в ресурсах. Названия групп храню в одном массиве, строки самих групп храню в разных строковых массивах, хочу хранить информацию о все нужных массивах в одном. Как можно передать имя массива как элемент другого в ресурсах - пытаюсь сделать так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <integer-array name="captions_item">
        <item>@array/geometry</item>
        <item>@array/probability_theory_captions</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

имхо, это нелучшие решение такой звдачи. такие данные лучше хранить в бд, а еще лучше в xml, которую потом можно правильно прочитать парсером. решить твою задачу можно введя какой-то маркер перед именем категорий, например, "theme:название_категории", а потом при разборе этого массива проверять начало и если элемент начинается с theme: - выделять его как категорию в списке